# Which files should be added to version control after setting up service worker using workbox-cli

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

After installing workbox and running the following to generate a service worker, there are 5 new files generated. I want to know which files should be version controlled or if they should be generated during the build process.

- `workbox wizard`
- `workbox generateSW public/SW.js`

The files generated are:

- sw.js
- sw.js.map
- workbox-config.js
- workbox-ec19d65c.js
- workbox-ec19d65c.js.map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`workbox-config.js` contains the configuration created by `workbox wizard`. You should check that in to version control so that you don't need to run `workbox wizard` again in the future.

The other files are all build artifacts, and I'd normally recommend not checking them in to version control. They will be regenerated after each build.